# Unhandled expression at line :

Tags: javascript, expression, loader, scene, babylonjs

So i am playing around with Babylon. In a `createScene` function I am also loading the `AssetManager`.

Whenever i add a task, it will throw errors: `unhandled expression` [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43xRU.png) for every line of my HTML document.

This also happens, if I ignore my `assetManager` and put in `SceneLoader.ImportMesh` instead.

I really dont know what to do anymore.

Thats my assetManager:

```
function assetManager() {
    var assetsManager = new BABYLON.AssetsManager(scene);
    var meshTask = assetsManager.addMeshTask("baum", "", "assets/", "carAcura.obj");

    meshTask.onSuccess = function (task) {
        task.loadedMeshes[0].position = BABYLON.Vector3.Zero();
        engine.loadingUIText = "Loaded asset " + task.loadedMeshes[0].name;
        console.log(task.loadedMeshes[0].name);
    }

    assetsManager.onTaskError = function (task) {
        console.log("error on Loading" + task.name);
    }

    assetsManager.load();

    assetsManager.onFinish = function (tasks) {
        console.log("done");
        engine.runRenderLoop(function () {
            if (engine.webGLVersion === 1) {
                pixiRenderer.reset();
            }
            scene.render();
            engine.wipeCaches(true);

            pixiRenderer.reset();
            pixiRenderer.render(stage);

            divFps.innerHTML = engine.getFps().toFixed() + " FPS";

            //loop();
        });
    };
};
```

Comment: Switching file format (and corresponding loader) from obj to glTF worked for me.